# Smack API User search

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm try to implement a user search on top of my working Smack-API based jabber client.It can create user using:

```
AccountManager manager = conn.getAccountManager();
manager.createAccount(usename,password);
```

However I need to add a functionality that will first search for "existing" user before it creates the account, but I can't find any straightforward way to do it. Anyone can provide me hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently what's needed is just to catch the error code 409 in the XMPPException, as createAccount throws exception if user exist.

Comment: The error can catched as follows -----if(e.getXMPPError().equals(XMPPError.Condition.conflict)){...}

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't actually need the functionality you requested any more (according to your own answer), I will answer the original question anyway for future reference.

There is a class called **UserSearchManager** in Smack that can be used for this purpose.

Comment: I may need to use UserSearchManager, because I need to check the email address if it exist already in the database, because I need to register by email. However for the question I have posted, its really just about createAccount() function.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to log in as the user once, *without* sending presence.  In general, we try to find all of the ways you could answer this question without having the ability to log in as the user, and eliminate them, in order to help prevent spim.